# flocker-docker-plugin not working on centos7.2

Tags: plugins, docker

I am trying to integrate flocker with docker, for that I found plugin flocker-docker-plugin. I installed it by using the commands on my flocker agents.-

```
$ yum install -y clusterhq-flocker-docker-plugin
$ systemctl enable flocker-docker-plugin
$ systemctl restart flocker-docker-plugin
```

It shows flocker-docker-plugin is running. However after few seconds when I checked status by using `$ systemctl status flocker-docker-plugin`, I got error saying

> flocker-docker-plugin.service: main process exited, code=killed,   status=11/SEGV

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have given there could be multiple reasons for this error:

Check if you can reach the flocker control service and more so if your node-agents can reach the control-service.

Check if the flocker-dataset-agent and the flocker-container-agent are running on your nodes.

Check if you have provided certificates for the flocker-docker-plugin as mentioned on their site (https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/latest/docker-integration/generate-api-plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

While installing flocker i also got the same error as we have just installed the docker plugin and by default it does't start's up.

First use the command `systemctl start flocker-docker-plugin` and then check the running status of flocker using `systemctl status flocker-docker-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the control service and dataset agent are running correctly first, you can find logs by looking in `/var/log/flocker/`, `journalctl -u flocker-dataset-agent` or running `flocker-diagnostics`.

Read through any error in these logs such as communication with control service issues, certificates issues, agent.yml config issues etc, or feel free to post them for more help.

You can also find `flocker-docker-plugin` logs the same way to see specific errors that may be occurring.

Here is more information about [how to debug flocker](https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/latest/administering/debugging.html#debugging-flocker).